# What is the best way to represent tree structure in memory as a cache?

Tags: c++, qt, data-structures, caching, treeview

Hello all
I have tree with nodes. The nodes are constructed by TCP API request response value.
To make less requests I'd like to represent the tree in a cache structure, that each time when TCP request are about to be invoked
it will check the cache first.
What is the best way to do it? I mean the tree cache part, in my case I'm using Qt and C++.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `std:map<TCPRequest, TCPResponse>` to achieve this.  Your request and response could be string in which case that might reduce to `std:map<std::string, std::string>`.  if not, you would need to ensure that your `TCPRequest` class supports `operator<` to allow the map to be binary searched.

Your code might look something like

```
#include <map>

std::map<TCPRequest, TCPResponse> responseCache;
typedef std::map<TCPRequest, TCPResponse>::const_iterator cacheCIterator;

TCPRequest nextRequest;
cacheCIterator iter = responseCache.find(nextRequest);
if (iter != responseCache.end())
{
  return iter->second;  // found cached response
}
else
{
  // issue the request
  TCPResponse response = issueRequest(nextRequest);

  //save the response
  responseCache[nextRequest] = response;
  return response;
}
```

You also need to consider cache expiry, unless your traffic is small enough that you can just cache all responses.  At some point you want to `erase()` `TCPResponse` objects from the map, possibly by keeping a separate structure that tells you which response was least recently used (LRU).

With this in mind some kind of unique identifier (a monotonically-increasing `int` would work) could be used in your `TCPResponse` objects as a proxy to the full objects, allowing you to identify the cache and LRU responses using `int`s instead of the full class instances.  You still need full `TCPRequest` comparison in order to ensure the cache works as desired, though.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider a hash map in case the number of outstanding requests is large. See QHash in the QT library, or std::hash_map (depending on the flavor of the STL you are using).